# .android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, kotlin, windows-10

Have reinstalled android studio and created new project but the problem persists .
This is what the error is !
File C:\Users\admin.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 29 not accepted.